# flutter riverpod question: watch a provider from another provider and trigger action on the first provider

Tags: riverpod

I am trying to figure out how can i watch a `StateNotifierProvider` and trigger some methods (defined in the class subclassing `StateNotifier`) on this provider after having done some `async` computations in another Provider watching the `StateNotifierProvider`.

**Loking at the example below**

i need to perform a `reset` from the `RandomAdderNotifier`object provided by the `randomAdderProvider` if  the `doneProvider` return `true`.

I try to reset from the `doReset` Provider. However the provider has nothing to provide.

**The point is** that both the `doneProvider` and the `doreset` provider are not rebuild on state changes of `AdderProvider`.

```dart
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Home());
  }
}

final randomProvider = Provider<Random>((ref) {
  return Random(1234);
});

//immutable state
class RandomAdder extends Equatable {
  final int sum;
  const RandomAdder(this.sum);
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [sum];
}

//State notifier extension
class RandomAdderNotifier extends StateNotifier<RandomAdder> {
  RandomAdderNotifier(this.ref) : super(const RandomAdder(0));
  final Ref ref;

  void randomIncrement() {
    state = RandomAdder(state.sum + ref.read(randomProvider).nextInt(5));
  }

  void reset() {
    state = RandomAdder(0);
  }
}

/// Providers are declared globally and specify how to create a state
final randomAdderProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<RandomAdderNotifier, RandomAdder>(
  (ref) {
    return RandomAdderNotifier(ref);
  },
);

Future<bool> delayedRandomDecision(ref) async {
  int delay = ref.read(randomProvider).nextInt(5);
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: delay));
  print("You waited $delay seconds for a decision.");
  return delay > 4;
}

final doneProvider = FutureProvider<bool>(
  (ref) async {
    ref.watch(randomAdderProvider);
    bool decision = await delayedRandomDecision(ref);
    print("the decision is $decision");
    return decision;
  },
);

final doreset = Provider((ref) {
  if (ref.watch(doneProvider).value!) {
    ref.read(randomAdderProvider.notifier).reset();
  }
});

class Home extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Counter example')),
      body: Center(
        // Consumer is a widget that allows you reading providers.
        child: Consumer(builder: (context, ref, _) {
          final count = ref.watch(randomAdderProvider);
          return Text('$count');
        }),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        // The read method is a utility to read a provider without listening to it
        onPressed: () =>
            ref.read(randomAdderProvider.notifier).randomIncrement(),
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `ref.listen` is more appropriate for usage within the doreset function than `ref.watch`.

> Similarly to ref.watch, it is possible to use ref.listen to observe a provider.
>
> The main difference between them is that, rather than rebuilding the widget/provider if the listened to provider changes, **using ref.listen will instead call a custom function.**

### **As per the Riverpod documentation**

- For `ref.listen` we need an additional argument - the callback function that we wish to execute on state changes - [Source](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading/#using-reflisten-to-react-to-a-provider-change)

> The ref.listen method needs 2 positional arguments, the first one is the Provider and the second one is the callback function that we want to execute when the state changes.
>
> The callback function when called will be passed 2 values, the value of the previous State and the value of the new State.

&

- We will need to handle an `AsyncValue` - [Source](https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/future_provider/#usage-example-reading-a-configuration-file:%7E:text=As%20you%20can%20see%2C%20listening%20to%20a%20FutureProvider%20inside%20a%20widget%20returns%20an%20AsyncValue%20%E2%80%93%20which%20allows%20handling%20the%20error/loading%20states)

> As you can see, listening to a FutureProvider inside a widget returns an AsyncValue – which allows handling the error/loading states.

### **In Practice**

1. doreset function

   I chose to handle the AsyncValue by only handling the data case with `state.whenData()`

```dart
final doReset = Provider<void>(
  (ref) {
    final done = ref.listen<AsyncValue<bool>>(doneProvider, (previousState, state) {
      state.whenData((value) {
        if (value) {ref.read(randomAdderProvider.notifier).reset();}
      });
    });
  },
);
```

2. Don't forget to watch either `doReset`/`doneProvider`  in your Home Widget's build method. Without that neither will kick off (Don't have an explanation for this behaviour)

```dart
class Home extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    ref.watch(doReset);
    ...
```

3. Lastly, your random function will never meet the condition for true that you have setup as `delay>4`, as the max possible delay is 4. Try instead using `delay>3` or `delay=4`.

   Also perhaps disable the button to prevent clicks while awaiting updates

Answer (score 1):

and in a case where you are using `ChangeNotifier` You can pass `ref` in you provider and use the `ref` same as we can use in `ConsumerWidget`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class YourProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  Ref ref;

  YourProvider(this.ref) : super();

  callOtherProviderFromThisProvider() {
    ref.read(otherProvider).someMethodINeedToTrigger();
  }
}

final yourProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<YourProvider>(
    (ref) => YourProvider(ref));
```